# Simplifying $\frac{e^{nx} - 1}{e^{nx} - e^x}$ to be able to solve for x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

I am trying to solve the above formula for x, and having a hard time simplifying this formula any more than this:

$$\frac{e^{nx} - 1}{e^{nx} - e^x}-c=0$$

*c* and *n* in this case are known constants.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: How is this question related to abstract algebra? Voting for closure.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't quite know which tags to put. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Put $t=e^x$ and you can simplify it to $(c-1)t^n - ct+1 = 0$, an n-th degree polynomial. There's no explicit solution formula for those when $n\ge5$. (I'm ignoring the $t=1$ solution which a bogus one since it makes the denominator of the original equation zero.) Solutions can be approximated by numerical methods like Newton's method.

Comment: I see, thank you for your help! I'll definitely try and submit with the correct tags next time.